# Couldn't get selected value from list(jsp, sevlet)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

Sorry for my bad english:)
Could someone help me. I've created list with names of employees. Every employee should have own page when you click it name, with information about choosen employee.
This is form:

```
<form name="submitForm" method="get" action="zakaz" id="form1"  class="dropdown-menu">
<%for(int i=0;i<dataList4.size();i++){%>
<input type="hidden" name="fio" value="<%=dataList4.get(i)%>">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:500px;">
<li><a href=# onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();return false;"><%=dataList4.get(i)%></a></li>
</ul>
  <%}%>
 </form>
```

this is servlet:

```
String fio = request.getParameter("fio");
   String query = "select * from culture where name like'"+fio+"'";
   try{
            try (Statement s = con.createStatement()) {
                s.executeQuery(query);
                rs = s.getResultSet();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    dataList4.add(rs.getString("name"));
                    dataList4.add(rs.getString("room"));
                    dataList4.add(rs.getString("number"));
                }

                rs.close();
            }
             }catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Exception is ;" + e);
        }

   request.setAttribute("dataList4",dataList4); 
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/zakaz.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

and forwards to another JSP:

```
<body>
        <%
List booklist=new ArrayList();
booklist=(ArrayList)request.getAttribute("dataList4");
for(int i=0;i<booklist.size();i++){
 booklist.get(i);
}
%>
<ul>  
   <li>ФИО: <span><%=booklist.get(0) %></span></li>
    <li>Кабинет:<span> <%=booklist.get(1) %></span></li>
    <li>Телефон: <span><%=booklist.get(3) %></span> </li>
</ul>
```

All datas taken from db Mysql, when i did like that, I get  information  of only first employee in the list, it didn't work for every employee.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind if i see your code is 'SQL injection attac'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form name="submitForm" method="get" action="zakaz" id="form1"  class="dropdown-menu">
 <input type="hidden" name="fio" id="fio" >
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:500px;">
  <%for(int i=0;i<dataList4.size();i++){%>       
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submitForm('<%=dataList4.get(i)%>')"><%=dataList4.get(i)%></a></li>
 <%}%>
</ul>
```

```
<script>
 function submitForm(name){
  document.getElementById("fio").value = name;
  document.forms['form1'].submit();
 // return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything works fine now! It's because of i don't know javascript)))

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
<input type="hidden" name="fio" value="<%=dataList4.get(i)%>">
```

in a loop you are going to create many lines with the same name (check the HTML source)

either use a GET and append this parameter to url or create and array of `fio`

**edit**

You html will look like

```
<form name="submitForm" method="get" action="zakaz" id="form1"  class="dropdown-menu">
<input type="hidden" name="fio" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="fio" value="234">
<input type="hidden" name="fio" value="345">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:500px;">
<li><a href=# onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();return false;">123</a></li>
<li><a href=# onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();return false;">234</a></li>
<li><a href=# onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();return false;">345</a></li>
</ul>
```

I would change this from a form POST to a GET

```
<a href="myServlet?fio='<%=dataList4.get(i)%>'">123
```

or use jquery / javascript to get the value and submit on you behalf.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but because of my bad english i can't understand this one:either use a GET and append this parameter to url may you show me with example. About array of fio, if i understand correctly it should be like this:String fio[] = request.getParameter("fio"); Instead of String fio = request.getParameter("fio"); But what can i do with array, how it will know which one is chosen?

Answer (score -1):

I think you for loop should come inside `<ul>` tag

```
<form name="submitForm" method="get" action="zakaz" id="form1"  class="dropdown-menu">
<ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:500px;">
<%for(int i=0;i<dataList4.size();i++){%>
<input type="hidden" name="fio<%=i%>" value="<%=dataList4.get(i)%>">
<li><a href=# onclick="document.forms['form1'].submit();return false;"><%=dataList4.get(i)%></a></li>
<%}%>
</ul>
 </form>
```

Also name is same for all elements. So you have to change that `name="fio<%=i%>"`.

Then you can access it in your servlet by

```
String fio = request.getParameter("fio0");
String fio = request.getParameter("fio1");
```

etc.